# Calculating Bayesian Probability for Multiple "Tests"

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm wanting to calculate the Bayesian probability of a Stock price going up or down based on multiple indicators.

There is an abundance of clear literature on calculating the Bayesian probability for a single "test" / indicator, but I'm having trouble finding anything regarding having multiple tests / indicators.

So for example, if I'm using 2 indicators:

a) A Moving Average
b) Candlestick Engulfing patterns

I'm able to obtain historic data and determine the "accuracy" of each of these indicators. Again for example, let's say that a) correctly predicts the direction of the Stock price 65% of the time, and b) 60% of the time.

What I want to do is calculate the Bayesian Probability that:

1. if a) + b) both indicate the price will go up, what is the Bayesian Probability that it will go up
2. if a) + b) both indicate the price will go up, what is the Bayesian Probability that it will go DOWN
3. if a) + b) both indicate the price will go down, what is the Bayesian Probability that it will go down
4. if a) + b) both indicate the price will go down, what is the Bayesian Probability that it will go UP

A related question, which may supersede the above - is the above question valid, or is the correct way of determining the Bayesian probability to  determine the accuracy of a) + b) by obtaining it from the historic data directly? In other words, to find all the occurrences in the historic data where a) + b) happen, then see what the accuracy is?

Comment: Be aware that stock prices are a random walk.